# How to add links into a D3 simulation when building a force directed graph the React / JSX way

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to build a force directed graph using D3, but where I use React/JSX for rendering and only d3 for the math.

I found an article here that explains how to add the nodes to the simulation and draw it. https://reactfordataviz.com/articles/force-directed-graphs-with-react-and-d3v7/

However I can't seem to do the same for the links as it's suggested at the end of the article.

I tried to fork the example in the article and commented out the "links" part of the code, to avoid the code sandbox to crash:

Here's the code (running sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/collision-force-forked-p1o9y9)

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

function ForceGraph({ nodes, charge }) {
  const [animatedNodes, setAnimatedNodes] = useState([]);
  // const [animatedLinks, setAnimatedLinks] = useState([]);

  // re-create animation every time nodes change
  useEffect(() => {
    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation()
      .force("x", d3.forceX(400))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(300))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(charge))
      .force("collision", d3.forceCollide(5));
    // .force('links', d3.forceLink());
    // alternatively: .force('link', d3.forceLink(links));

    // update state on every frame
    simulation.on("tick", () => {
      setAnimatedNodes([...simulation.nodes()]);
      // setAnimatedLinks([...simulation.links()]);
    });

    // copy nodes into simulation
    simulation.nodes([...nodes]);
    // simulation.links([...links]);
    // slow down with a small alpha
    simulation.alpha(0.1).restart();

    // stop simulation on unmount
    return () => simulation.stop();
  }, [nodes, charge]);

  return (
    <g>
      {animatedNodes.map((node) => (
        <circle
          cx={node.x}
          cy={node.y}
          r={node.r}
          key={node.id}
          stroke="black"
          fill="transparent"
        />
      ))}
    </g>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [charge, setCharge] = useState(-3);

  // create nodes with unique ids
  // radius: 5px
  const nodes = useMemo(
    () =>
      d3.range(50).map((n) => {
        return { id: n, r: 5 };
      }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React & D3 force graph</h1>
      <p>Current charge: {charge}</p>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="-30"
        max="30"
        step="1"
        value={charge}
        onChange={(e) => setCharge(e.target.value)}
      />
      <svg width="800" height="600">
        <ForceGraph nodes={nodes} charge={charge} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also tried passing links directly like this `.force('link', d3.forceLink(links));`

If I then do some transformation of the links like this:

```
const obj: any = {};
    nodes.forEach((d, i) => {
      obj[d.id] = i; // create an object to look up a node's index by id
    });

    links?.forEach((d) => {
      d.source = obj[d.source]; // look up the index of source
      d.target = obj[d.target]; // look up the index of target
    });
```

I get to another error message

When I write simulation.links()  to attempt to get them back and set them to React state, I just get the error "simulation.links() is not a function"

But no matter what I do I cannot seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the same article and was puzzled why it included "simulation.links" even though I could never find it anywhere else in Observable or even the d3-force api. But I was able to find a solution!

Since we are able to get "simulation.nodes" we are able to create a new memoized function for links by creating referencing the nodes by their id.

```
        const lineLinks = useMemo(() => {
            const nodeMap = keyBy(beeData, 'id')
            return beeLinks.map((link) => {
                return {
                    ...link,
                    source:
                        nodeMap[typeof link.source === 'object' ? link.source.id : ''],
                    target:
                        nodeMap[typeof link.target === 'object' ? link.target.id : ''],
                }
            })
        }, [beeData, beeLinks])
```

I followed the same article so you because we already have

```
setBeeData([...(simulation.nodes() as DirectionNode[])])
```

We can watch `beeData` because the simulation at least gives us the nodes which the article also used to track via a useState hook.

Comment: Other than being shorter or there any other reason you chose useMemo over useState and useEffect? :-) Thanks for sharing your solution.
And could you please also share where you feed the links into d3?